# How do I use geocode in python to convert singapore's postal code into lat lng?

Tags: python, gis, geocoding

I need help. This is my first coding GIS in python. So my task is to convert this postal codes that are from singapore into lat n lng coordinates before passing them into the geometry column of a geodataframe. But I am having trouble converting the postal codes to lat lng coordinates and I am not exactly sure what's the problem.
=======================================================================#

```
  Postal_Code

0 237978

1 731678

2 259727

3 569922

4 470632
```

### Convert to lat lng method ( obtained from @Miguel2488 on Stacks )

```
import csv

import geocoder

import geopandas as gpd

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("My File name")

saved_column = df.Postal_Code

saved_column.head()



lat_lng_coords = None

while(lat_lng_coords is None):

   g = geocoder.google('{}, Singapore'.format(saved_column))

   lat_lng_coords = g.latlng

latitude = lat_lng_coords[0]

longitude = lat_lng_coords[1]

print(latitude, longitude)
```

Comment: Where is your code for making http request to google geocoding API? See [Geocoding API developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests).

Comment: “Having trouble” isn’t a problem description that is possible to solve. You need to be specific about what the problem with your code is for example given a certain input, what output does it give, and what were you expecting. Be specific.